# Sony PCG-252L white screen help

Tags: graphics-card, white-screen

I have a Sony PCG-252L All-in-one desktop. Last week it downloaded some updates, restarted, and ever since then it is shows nothing but a white screen.

I can hear the beeps on startup, screen changes from white to black a couple of times, and then stays white.

There's no VGA or HDMI port on the computer, so I can't plug it into the external monitor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anything else work? If you press the caps-lock key after it's booted for a while, does the led on the keyboard toggle? If so, it's apparently gotten far enough into the OS to initialize the devices.
Also, I'd imagine that it has a BIOS splash screen. Does that show either?

Comment: keyboard works just fine ... BIOS splash screen doens't show either ... it's WHITE from the very beginning

Comment: Is there a small reset hole somewhere?  One you have to use a pen with?

Comment: What updates did you install?  Windows Updates?

Answer (score 0):

this has to my sony (same model) constantly.  The easiest way to continue your work without restarting is to do CTRL ALT DEL, and you will see a IE running, actually states blank or white screen. End the program and presto - you are back to your desktop.